# Better way to find regexp in emacs buffer

Tags: buffers, regular-expressions, search

I'm trying to make a function to read a whole buffer and find lines that match with regexp, I think to read the whole buffer and save to list of strings but I read that it's very inefficient. Whats the better form of do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is really unclear what you want to do, but if you are looking for an "end in itself" interactive use, then you are probably covered by one of [`occur` et al](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Other-Repeating-Search.html): e.g., <kbd>M-x occur RET TODO RET</kbd>.

If this is a step in a long processing chain, you should start with the sources for the above commands and ask a separate, more specific question.

Comment: What I want to to it's to find lines in code files to contain the ```TODO:``` word.

Comment: @rafaelleru: see edit.